# Simple slim session manager not read session in a different function

Tags: php, session, slim

I am using the following slim session manager(https://github.com/bryanjhv/slim-session). I have separate functions for `login`, `logout` and `user_data`.

```
$app->post("/login", function() use ($app)
        {
             $input = $app->request()->getBody();
           $input = json_decode($input);
            try 
            {

                if ($input->username && $input->password) 
                    {
                        $user = Model::factory('Users')->where("username",$input->username)->where("password",md5($input->password))->find_one();
                    $session = new \SlimSession\Helper; 
                    //set session
                    $session->set('userid', $user->id);


                        $status = 'success';
                        $message = 'Logged in successfully.';
                    } 
                else
                        {
                            $status = 'danger';
                            $message = 'Could not log you in. Please try again.';
                        }

            }
            catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        $status = 'danger';
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
            $response = array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message,
            );
            $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            echo json_encode($response);

        });



        $app->post("/logout",function() use ($app)
        {

            try {
                        $session = new \SlimSession\Helper;
                    $session::destroy();

                        $status = 'success';
                        $message = 'You have been logged out successfully';
                    } 

            catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        $status = 'danger';
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
            $response = array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message
            );

            $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            echo json_encode($response);

        });


$app->get("/user_data", function() use ($app)
        {

            try 
             {
                    $session = new \SlimSession\Helper;
                    //get session
                    $userid = $session->get('userid');
                  $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
                if ($_SESSION['userid'])
                    {
                        $users = Model::factory('Users')->where('id',$_SESSION['userid'])->find_one();
                        $response = array(
             'id'=>$users->id,
                            'username'=>$users->username,
                            'email'=>$users->email,
                            'phone_number'=>$users->phone_number,
                            'password'=>$users->password,
                            'type'=>$users->type,
                            'credits'=>$users->credits,
                            'profile_picture'=>$users->profile_picture,




                        ); 

                    }
                else
                {
                    $status = "danger";
                    $message = 'You need to be logged in to do that.';

                    $response = array(
                    'status' => $status,
                    'message' => $message
                    );
                }

             } 
            catch (Exception $e) 
                {
                    $status = "danger";
                    $message = $e->getMessage();

                    $response = array(
                    'status' => $status,
                    'message' => $message
                    );
                }


            $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            echo json_encode($response);

        });
```

The problem I am having is that when the user logs in I set a `session` variable in the */login* function. But when the `session` variable i set in `login` function isn't being retrieved in the */user_data* function.

Anyone knows whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Have you started session with session_start() ?

Correct logic to check session is as follows:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    // session exists
    // do further work
}
```

Comment: the session is working within the same function. Forexample, if i set a session variable within the /login function and retrieve it within the same function, it works fine, but if i retrieve it in a different function forexample /user_data, then the value can't be retrieved